# New line added in NSString with /n but how to center both lines of string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
 NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu \n", step];
        NSString *currentSteps = [st stringByAppendingString:NSLocalizedString(@"steps", "")];
 [_circleProgressBar setHintTextGenerationBlock:(^NSString *(CGFloat progress) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", currentSteps];
        } )];
```

I have number of steps its showing now like this:
0
steps

But rather it would be nice to get 0 should be in center of string steps.

Comment: String is just a object that holds a value and has nothing to do with how it presenten in a UI. You can `UILabel` with content mode center.

Comment: Hi, I am using CircleProgressBar API, which has only one text to be showed and inside i have to do that. That is my limitation. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: You could maybe use `NSAttributedString` with a paragraph and set the alignment to center.

Comment: If you can give me the example it will be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `NSAttributedString` with a paragraph with centers the text.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle];

NSAttributedString *label = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:currentSteps attributes:attributes]
```